Reset/clear flask session upon browser refresh
Is it possible to clear user session (restart from new) when user refresh the web page?
Setting app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False clear session on browser exit. I would like to have the same beaviour upon refresh.

I might not think it through, isn't this equivalent to not using session at all? After all the whole point of using session is to preserve state between requests. If you need it to expire on every new request (refresh), then it is stateless between requests and you don't need cookies and sessions at all.
